# How can i set cascade mode Globally?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, fluentvalidation

I am new to .net core web API. I am using fluent validation API for model validation. I want to set cascade option globally for all validators. I found following line

```
ValidatorOptions.CascadeMode = CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure;
```

in [Given Link](https://fluentvalidation.net/start#setting-the-cascade-mode)

But I am confused where to write this line and in which function.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That class is a static, so you set it as early in the pipeline as you reasonable can:

> To set the cascade mode globally, you can set the CascadeMode property
>   on the static ValidatorOptions class during your application’s startup
>   routine

In a Net Core application that would be in the **Startup** class

You should have something like this:

```
public class Startup
{
    // Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...
    }

    // Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        **ValidatorOptions.CascadeMode = CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure;**  
    }
}
```

Add it somewhere like that

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is not quite clear, if you are using .NET Core you can set the cascade mode at a global level like below

```
.AddFluentValidation(fv =>
            {
                fv.RunDefaultMvcValidationAfterFluentValidationExecutes = true;
                fv.ValidatorOptions.CascadeMode = CascadeMode.Stop;

                fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Startup>();
            });
```